# R vector of sequences being indexed by boolean values?

Tags: r

I have the following R code:

```
simul <- function() {
  x <- sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
  s <- cumsum(c(0, x))
}

(tmp = simul())

(1:(n - 1))[tmp[1:(n - 1)] * tmp[3:(n + 1)] < 0]
```

I understand that `1:(n - 1)` generates a vector of a sequence from 1 to n - 1 for each n, meaning there are potentially many such vectors (if n > 2). I also know that `tmp[1:(n - 1)] * tmp[3:(n + 1)] < 0` returns are TRUE/FALSE value. Therefore, it seems that, for each vector `1:(n - 1)`,  `tmp[1:(n - 1)] * tmp[3:(n + 1)] < 0` generates a boolean value. But this means that `(1:(n - 1))[tmp[1:(n - 1)] * tmp[3:(n + 1)] < 0]` indexes each vector by a boolean value, which doesn't make sense to me.

Furthermore, it seems that at the end of this process, `(1:(n - 1))[tmp[1:(n - 1)] * tmp[3:(n + 1)] < 0]` returns a vector of integers, but of what?

Comment: See what `(1:4)[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]` gives.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Got it. It gives the vector `1 3`, obviously representing the 1 FALSE and 3 TRUE values. But what process is it undergoing here?

Comment: No, the vector `1 3` comes from the `TRUE` (where they are located). Indexing by a logical vector does not return the `FALSE`, only the `TRUE` index values. Also, compare to `(1:4)[c(TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE)]` and to `(1:4)[which(c(TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE))]`. Be carefull with `NA`'s.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Ahh, thank you for the clarification. And I was mistaken about `(1:(n - 1))`; it just produces a single vector of an integer sequence from 1 to n - 1?

Comment: Yes, even if `n` is not an integer. Example: `1:(pi - 1)`.

Comment: Think vectorized in R, `1:4` is c(`1, 2, 3, 4)` and `TRUE`/ `FALSE` is yes / no. 1=yes, 2=no, 3=yes, 4=no is: `(1:4)[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]`. BTW why does `(1:4)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` give the same result? :)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Ok, this all makes sense to me now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @jay.sf Hmm, that *is* weird. `(1:4)[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]` clearly gives the correct answer, but  `(1:4)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` is recognizing an extra TRUE value at position 3 that doesn't actually exist? Is it that `(1:4)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` is reiterating through the first and second positions, since the the first part is (1:4), so it just starts at the beginning again once it hits the end of the vector [c(TRUE, FALSE)]?

Comment: Yes, it's called "recycling", [the recycling rule](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) might be a brief introductory read for you.